# What do you call one that believes God will always grant him/her his wishes? Instead trusting that God will ultimately decide according to His will

Tags: meaning

I am a chaplain working in palliative services. I have to document my visits and I am always searching for the right vocabulary that can accurately describe each patient's particular beliefs and spiritual and/or emotional circumstances.
I often encounter people who believe that God will consistently grant their wishes if they only have enough faith.  I would like a word to describe that belief without making a judgment as to the accuracy or misconception of said belief.

Comment: What kind of wishes? Pious prayers for nice things to happen to good people, desire for money and worldly success, wishing for evil things to happen to other people?

Comment: A theist. An atheist won't depend on gods for anything.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it belong on https://christianity.stackexchange.com

Comment: Contented. After all, whatever happens in their life, they believe that God is giving them everything they desire.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your description correctly, the belief itself is called [***prosperity theology***](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prosperity_theology) (among other names):

> Prosperity theology (sometimes referred to as the prosperity gospel, the health and wealth gospel, the gospel of success, or seed faith) is a religious belief among some Charismatic Christians that financial blessing and physical well-being are always the will of God for them, and that **faith, positive speech, and donations to religious causes will increase one's material wealth.**  ... Prosperity theology views the Bible as a contract between God and humans: **if humans have faith in God, God will deliver security and prosperity.**

Answer (score 0):

If looking for a neutral way of describing the belief in a God that helps people, I'd use the word **interventionist**.

> The person holds an interventionist view of the deity, trusting that a truly devout prayer will be answered.

Another way that this attitude towards God has been described is the belief in **a personal God**.

> The person believes in  a personal God, that God hears their prayers, and that by praying they are *communing* with God.

Comment: Your description of "personal God" doesn't imply a belief that God grants wishes. All Christians believe God hears their prayers, but few that I know believe God will always answer in the way they wish he would. There's a saying, "God answers all prayers, but sometimes the answer is 'no'."

Comment: @nnnnnn ... Aslan is not a tame lion.

Comment: @nnnnnn  It depends on who you ask. BBC.co.uk: *Christians believe that God is concerned with the lives of people, working miracles and answering their prayers. In this way, Christians believe that God is a ‘personal’ God, meaning a being they can develop a relationship with.*  https://www.bbc.co.uk/bitesize/guides/zf626yc/revision/1#:~:text=Christians%20believe%20that%20God%20is%20concerned%20with%20the%20lives%20of,can%20develop%20a%20relationship%20with.   The point is that sometimes, they believe, the answer is "Yes".

Comment: @TimR - Sure, but the question asked about people who believe God will _always_ grant their wishes.

Comment: @nnnnnn Indeed, hadn't read the question title carefully. In the body of the question it says "consistently".